# Filtered dropdown based on 1st choice

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been looking around Stack Overflow for some guidance regarding dynamic dropdown lists. However, most seem to be based around creating a category header and then the values for each header below it. I have a different setup that is making it hard for me to adjust that method to my issue, because I want to filter the 2nd column based on the first dropdown list's choice.
I have three columns of data (I only need two for this issue)
City, Name, Email

I have a list of delegates, many from the same cities. Example:

```
Boston          John Smith
Atlanta         Chris Jones
New York City   Alan Chan
Boston          Phillip Cho
Boston          Sarah Fieler
Atlanta         Eric Parks
```

I am trying to make two dropdown lists within Google Sheets. The first dropdown list is easy since I'll just select the entire column. However, I want to have the 2nd column to filter the values based on the first column so if it's Boston, it will only show John Smith, Phillip Cho and Sarah Fieler.

Is this possible? Any guidance would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
I wanted to add an update to Serge's answer.
I wanted to take it a step further and did not want to refresh the entire column's validation rules each time I selected a city so I modified the script by adding

```
var r = tSheet.getActiveCell();
  var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
  var rule   =SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().setAllowInvalid(true).requireValueInList(names).build();
  nextCell.setDataValidation(rule);
```

Now each time I modify the city column, it will only affect the cell next to it.
Hopefully someone else finds use for this. Thank you Serge

Comment: I guess you also want to remove duplicates in the first drop down don't you ? And also, do you need the validation to be available in a single cell or in the whole columns ?

Comment: Are data and dropdown lists in the same sheet ?

Comment: Looking for the data validation for the whole column. So, if I select the city on the first column it'll filter it for the 2nd column, but this is part of a schedule so there will be around 20 rows. Also, I have a contact sheet and a schedule sheet. So the schedule sheet is validating against the contact sheet.

Comment: OK, that's what I thought, I have a script that does exactly what you need but no time right now... I'll answer later.

Comment: there it is ;-) hoping you'll like it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a complete setup to get that behavior in your sheet.
I had to assume a few setup decisions that you will probably need to adapt to your requirements such as columns and sheet names.

The `TriggerSetup` function has to run just once to setup the `onEdit` trigger

`getCities()` should run on open or when you decide you need the first validation to be updated.

I added a small utility to remove duplicates in arrays, I needed it to create the validation lists without duplicates.

```
function setupTrigger(){
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onEditGetNames')
   .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
   .onEdit()
   .create();
}

function onEditGetNames(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var tSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col = ss.getActiveRange().getColumn();
  if(tSheet.getName()!='schedule' || col!=1){ // assuming city validation is in column A
    Logger.log('wrong sheet or wrong column');
    return;
  }
  var cityMatch = tSheet.getActiveCell().getValue();
  var data = ss.getSheetByName('contacts').getRange('A2:B').getValues();//assuming names are in column B
  var names = [];
  for(var n in data){
    if(data[n][0] == cityMatch && data[n][1] != ''){
      names.push(data[n][1]);
    }
  }
  names.sort();
  var tSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('schedule');
  var targetRange = tSheet.getRange('B2:B');
  targetRange.clearDataValidations();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().setAllowInvalid(true).requireValueInList(names).build();
  targetRange.setDataValidation(rule);
}

function getCities(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var data = ss.getSheetByName('contacts').getRange('A2:A').getValues();//assuming cities are in column A
  var city = [];
  for(var n in data){
    if(data[n][0] !=''){
      city.push(data[n][0]);
    }
  }
  city.sort();
  var tSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('schedule');
  var targetRange = tSheet.getRange('A2:A');
  targetRange.clearDataValidations();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().setAllowInvalid(true).requireValueInList(city).build();
  targetRange.setDataValidation(rule);
}

function removeDups(array){
  var data = array.slice();
  var outArray = [];
  data.sort(
    function(x,y){
      var xp = x.toLowerCase();
      var yp = y.toLowerCase();
    return xp > yp ? 1 : xp < yp ? -1 : 0;
    });
  outArray.push(data[0]);
  for(var n=0;n<data.length-1;n++){
    if(data[n+1]!=data[n]){outArray.push(data[n+1])}
  }
  return outArray;
}
```

Screen captures :

[image]
[image]

Comment: That worked out really well and was very informative. There seems to be one catch though. Every time a city is selected in the first column, it changes the validation contents for the 2nd column which invalidates all previous records.
So for example. In the screenshot, if i went back to Atlanta, and i wanted to choose Eric Parks, I'll only see the folks for Boston. Is there a way around this? also Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: That's normal since you wanted to have a new validation rule based on the city. I see no way to avoid it ...anyway, it just causes a visual warning, nothing else.

Comment: To modify a previous entry you should first delete the city and then reselect it to get the right validation for the names

Comment: Also one more interesting thing,  every time I modify a record, it adds onEditGetNames as a trigger. So by the time I modified 10 records, 10 triggers are there.

Comment: That should not happen...did you copy the script as it is ? The setup trigger function runs only manually, there is no possibility to have it run multiple times unless you do it yourself via the script editor...

Comment: That is so odd. I recreated it again and now it's good. Must've been something I've done. Thank you so much! As for the whole name column refreshing each time a city was chosen. Im going to see if there is a way to create the validation to just the cell next to the city cell that was modified.

Comment: Good idea.In the mean time please consider accepting this answer. Thx